# i am get all users list and then include which users complete kyc verified using foreign key

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

```
user list = user.objects.filter().values('username', 'user id', 'email', 'phone')

Query set [{'username': 'muthu12', 'user id': 25, 'email': 'muthu12@gmail.com', 'phone': '9047885819'}, {'username': 'muthu123', 'user id': 26, 'email': 'muthu123@gmail.com', 'phone': '9047885819'},
```

I'm expect this type of Query set, KYC is Foreign key,

```
query set : [{'username': 'muthu12', 'user id': 25, 'email': 'muthu12@gmail.com', 'phone': '9047885819', 'KYC' : True}, {'username': 'muthu123', 'user id': 26, 'email': 'muthu123@gmail.com', 'phone': '9047885819', 'KYC' : False},
```

this is KYC my model :

```
KYC id = Auto field, 
user id = one to one,
pan card = Char field,
DOB = Char field,
KYC status = Char field.
```

Comment: can you add the models code of user and kyc into the questions?

Comment: i,m update my kyc model .

Comment: I see that the query you want to return has a boolean of True False, but it doesn't exist in your KYC model. Can you post what determines the boolean value in the query?

Comment: Can possible manual add boolean field(only return this queryset) based on user kyc verified or not verified.

Comment: i presume the `KYC status` column determine if the KYC is verified or not?

Comment: no!! Users kyc verified  after this data stored on  database

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query to add new field using [annotation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) , [Exists](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/expressions/#exists-subqueries) and [OuterRef](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.OuterRef)

```
from django.db.models import Exists, OuterRef

user.objects.filter().values('username', 'user id', 'email', 'phone').annotate(
   kyc=Exists(KycModel.objects.filter(user_id=OuterRef('id'))
)
```

Explanations:

- annotate to add extra select statement
- Exists() to get boolean value from subquery
- OuterRef() to refer to the outside query contain user model field